# Linking a dynamic library into a static library (aka pre-linking a dynamic library)

Tags: c, dynamic, static, linker

I have a very small library that I'd like to turn to a static library (libx.a), but this library depends on a dynamic library (liby.so). I would like to be able to "pre-link" my static library, so that libx.a would already contain reference to liby.so.

This would basically allow me not to specify the option -ly when compiling a program where -lx is present. This makes things simpler when linking against libx, especially if it depends on many shared libraries.

Is it possible ? If yes, how (assuming gcc) ?

Still if possible, if the program using libx uses liby itself, will there be some kind of funny duplication (variables I suppose) going on ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm confused whether you really want to include the shared library code into the static library archive, or whether you want to just make it so linking the static library automatically creates a reference to the shared library as well.

In the former case, I know of no tools to do it, but it should be a solvable problem. You could probably make a tool to convert a `.so` file to a normal `.o` file if you spend some time reading the ELF specs, then just include the `.o` file in the `.a` archive.

In the latter case, most people solve this problem with `pkg-config`. Another approach, which would be rather GNU-specific, would be installing a GNU linker script instead of the raw `.a` file, and having the linker script reference both your static library and the required shared library.

Comment: I meant the latter. Thanks, I'll look into pkg-config :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that your dynamic library is compiled position-independent and needs a dynamic loader to fix the internal and external references at load time. Thus you cannot explicitly link against a dynamic library. In the project I'm working on we are usually compiling static and dynamic versions of libs and this is one of the reasons.

Comment: I understand this, but when you link an executable against a dynamic library, this dynamic load also needs to take place.

What I mean to do is not remove the dynamic load step, but simply to have the references to the dynamic library added to the static library directly. Then if we link the executable against the static library and run it, the references to the dynamic library that were in the static library will need to be resolved.

Comment: This is not a fundamental problem by any means. The dynamic-linking-oriented relocations in the `.so` could certainly be resolved at static-link time... There's nothing about PIC code that prevents it from being relocated to a fixed position.

Answer (score 0):

The problem can be solved by using an intelligent build system. I can recommend using [gyp](https://code.google.com/p/gyp/). It has the option `link_settings` for static libraries:

```
{
  'targets': [
    {
      'target_name': 'x',  # will generate libx.a
      'type': 'static_library',
      'sources': [],
      'link_settings': {
        'libraries': ['-ly'],
      },
    },
    {
      'target_name': 'test',
      'type': 'executable',
      'dependencies': ['x'],
      'sources': [],
    },
  ],
}
```